# mvc post two different object synchronously

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a model which has navigation property as well but the problem that I am having is that when I get data and when I want to edit I can load navigation property it self.

That's good but when I want to submit the data the navigation property returns `null`. I couldn't find a way to submit with its nav property. My aim is that I have a model and I have also a nav property.

I have two tables; one is named `customer` and the other is named `telephone`. So far it seems fine, but my `telephone` table should appear on the same page because when I want to edit or create they must work synchronously. If I am using MVC I must not take care of sending data to the server side as it has own function called form collection.

How can I load nav property and get this data on server side?

Comment: Add your view model and view here.

Comment: Can you post your existing code?

Comment: Please Share Your Code as requested by Other Users.

Answer (score 0):

Even though your question is Bit Unclear but here is what I infer from it
You said that you are trying to submit Customer as well as Telephone (Navigation property) Information. In Order to Achieve this we can have a ViewModel that contain both of these Entities. so you may need to write a View Model something as follows.

```
public class ViewModelName
{
   public Employee Emp {get; set;} // here Employee is your entity (Model)
   public Telephone Tel {get; set;} // here Telephone is your entity (Model)
} // Note I haven't tested the above piece of Code
```

Then In Create (Post and Get) Method you will send or get the ViewModelName Object. this will send both entity data as well as will receive both  entities data on submit.

you also said ***they must work synchronously*** I don't know what you exactly meant by that but you might need to Use Ajax if you want to see some real time changes going on without the Page being refreshed. Please share your code so that the stackoverflow Community can answer your Question to the point.